# What's the best way to 301 redirect pages in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have rewritten my site in Cakephp and choosen to keep the new Cakephp structure. I was wondering if I could use routing in Cakephp for 301-routing (permanently moved).

I want to redirect resources.php, languages.php, clips.php, possibly *.php, to /resources/, /languages/, /clips.

Can this type of 301 redirecting be easily done in CakePHP? I could even write a simple admin-interface to add 301-links, e.g. from a MySQL table to easily administer redirects. Or is it better to do this manually via mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about the best way, but I would first put routing at routes php like:

```
Router::connect('/resources.php', array(
    'controller' => 'resources', 
    'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

(and so on)

After that check at start of the action function which route was used, and if *.php route was used do a 301 redirect:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'resources', 'action' => 'index'), 301);
```

I guess there is also "smarter" way to implement this but this was the idea. (use of before_filter etc)

Answer (score 2):

Since CakePhp 2.x there is `Router::redirect()` method.

So you could add redirection in your routs:

```
Router::redirect(
    '/resources.php', 
    array(
        'controller' => 'resources', 
        'action' => 'index'
    ), 
    array('status' => 301)
);
```

The third parameter `array('status'=>301)` is not necessary because 301-redirect is used by default.

See [Redirect routing — CakePHP Cookbook v2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing).

Comment: if it is redirect, why controller and action is provided? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas, the second argument is an URL of landing page. You have two options to specify this: either string url like `'/landing/'` or an array specifying controller, action (and, probably, parameters) like `array('controller'=>'landing','action'=>'index')` to make `Router` prepare url for you.